# Should a Scala process be marked scala.concurrent.blocking within a Scala Future?

Tags: scala, akka

I have created a Scala process, I read that this is blocking, should it be wrapped in a scala.concurrent.blocking? I'm confused, since the Process is going to call back to the log parameter here which would require this thread to do something I guess, so its not completely blocking?

```
import scala.sys.process.Process
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger

def something = Future {
  val log = ProcessLogger(normal => {
    lines = lines :+ normal
    Logger.info("SFTPline added: " + normal)
  },
  error => {
      Logger.info("SFTPERROR: " + error)
  })

  val success = scala.concurrent.blocking {
    val result = Process(command).!(log)

    lines.mkString("").contains("\"success\":true") && (result == 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala Process is actually get execute by the [run](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder@run(log:scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger,connectInput:Boolean):scala.sys.process.Process) function which return [Process](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.Process) and exteciute it without blocking. the '!' is function that call the 'run' function and then call the exitValue() function of the Process.  the 'exitValue()' Blocks until proccess exits)
calling `Process(command).!(log)` is actually same as `run(log).exitValue()`  (well, not exactly but you can get the idea... see [ProcessBuilderImpl.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilderImpl.scala))
If you don't want to be blocked just call the run function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given that what you're returning is not a `Future`, your code must be blocking somewhere (I don't see how your example is "within a scala Future") - if you call a function that calls a callback, but then block waiting for that callback to be called, you're still blocking. So yes, declare it blocking.

Comment: Sorry, I implied that its all within a Future, here I have changed the code now to make that clear.